Interior of the set of probability measures
$\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal X}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal M}$
$\newcommand{\PR}{\mathcal P}$
Let $\X$ be a compact subset of $\R^d$. Let $\M$ denote the space of finite signed Borel measures on $\X$. Let $\M_1$ be the subset of $\M$ of measure with unit mass. Now, let $\M_+$ denote the set of non-negative Borel measures on $\X$.
We can endow $\M_1$ with the topology of weak convergence. Then $\PR=\M_+\cap M_1$ is a closed subset of $\M^1$. My question is the following.
Is there a simple way to characterise the probabilities that are in the interior $\PR^\circ$ of $\PR$?
If we consider the case where $\X$ has finite cardinality, then things are easy. Indeed everything reduces to finite dimensional vector spaces and $\PR^\circ$ consists simply of the probability vector that are everywhere strictly positive. This can still make sense is $\X$ is countable, but clearly it doesn't if $\X$ is uncountable.
Note that we can endow the whole $\M$ with the weak convergence topology. Then $\M_+$ is a closed set. Let $\M_+^\circ$ be its interior. Then I guess that $\PR^\circ = \M_+^\circ\cap\PR$. In practice, the boundary of $\PR$ would be those probability measures that are the weak limit of a sequence of measures not in $\M_+$. Then, $\PR^\circ$ would be the complementary of this set. However, I don't see easily how to give an explicit characterisation of the elements in $\PR^\circ$, as it was possible in the finite cardinality case. Is it the set of measure with full support? I guess it is not, but I am not sure.
Clearly any probability measure whose support is not the whole $\X$ cannot be in the interior. Indeed, let $P$ be such a measure and $x$ be outside of its support. Then $P-\varepsilon\delta_x$ tends weakly to $P$ but is made of measures not in $\M_+$. So, having full support is a requirement. But it does not seem to be enough...
Edit. I am wondering if the interior is actually non-empty if $\X$ is uncountable. Because for any $P$ there must be $x\in\X$ such that $P(\{x\})=0$. Now consider an arbitrary continuous and bounded function $f$. For $\varepsilon>0$, define $P_\varepsilon = P-\varepsilon \delta_x$. Then, for $\varepsilon\to 0$, $\langle P_\varepsilon, f\rangle = \langle P, f\rangle + \varepsilon f(x) \to \langle P, f\rangle$, so it seems to me that I always have a sequence of elements not in $\M_+$ that tends weakly to $P$...

Naive question on the counter-example in your edit. The dirac measure isn't in $\mathcal M$, is it? My intuition is that the counter examples are going to come from densities like $f(x) = 1 / \sqrt{|x|}$ which are unbounded but have finite integral at 0. I wonder if restricting to bounded densities would work?
